# this.props.getItemCount is not a function (VirtualizedList, React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I switched from using a FlatList to a VirtualizedList, and I got the error `this.props.getItemCount is not a function`. When I ran the debugger, the exception is thrown from VirtualizedList.js

```
<VirtualizedList
    data={contacts}
    getItem={(data, index) => data[index]}
    getItemCount={data => data.length}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ContactListItem
        name={item.name}
        number={item.number}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike FlatList, VirtualizedList requires the props getItem and getItemCount ([React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.25/virtualizedlist#getitemcount)).

```
<VirtualizedList
    data={contacts}
    getItem={(data, index) => data[index]}
    getItemCount={data => data.length}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <ContactListItem
        name={item.name}
        number={item.number}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: Why are you posting your own question again as the answer? You should have just added a comment to your original question.

Comment: Actually, answering your own question is considered good form on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @phatmann Yes, but it is a bit confusing what kind of problem was in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

If you used VirtualizedList and you still have the same error, use `SafeAreaView` import it from react-native and add FlatList inside it

```
import {FlatList,SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
<SafeAreaView>
  <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, i) => item.id.toString()}
    data={favoriteFilm}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <FavoritesItemFilm
        title={item.title}
        description={item.overview}
        vote={item.vote_count}
        release={item.release_date}
        image={item.poster_path}
        id={item.id}
      />
    )}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
```